# Use paths with accented characters in .command file on Mac

Tags: macos, command-line, encoding, filenames

I have a .command file on Mac where I need to run a command which contains two file paths, and both file paths contain a Swedish accented character (`ä`). Here is the command I need to run:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDZO -o ~/OneDrive/Documents/MittBästaProgram/install-mac-readonly.dmg ~/OneDrive/Documents/Mitt/BästaProgram/install-mac-readandwrite.dmg
```

Typing this manually in the terminal works just fine, but the problem is that the fact that the file path contains a `ä` makes this not work properly when I run it from a .command file. When I ran this .command file, I got an output where the `ä` in the file names was replaced by a question mark. This is the output I got:

```
line 1: 828 Segmentation fault: 11 hdiutil convert -format UDZO -o ~/OneDrive/Documents/MittB?staProgram/install-mac-readonly.dmg ~/OneDrive/Documents/Mitt/B?staProgram/install-mac-readandwrite.dmg
```

Since it replaced `ä` with question marks, it made me assume that it had problems with accented characters in file names. To be sure about that, I copied the files onto the desktop and tried running it from there (there are no accented characters in the path to the desktop):

```
hdiutil convert -format UDZO -o ~/Desktop/install-mac-readonly.dmg ~/Desktop/install-mac-readandwrite.dmg
```

This worked just fine, which means that the problem in the first one is the `ä` in the file path.

I know that there are similar problems on Windows with .bat files (the equivalent on Windows to .command files), and there the problem can be solved by adding `chcp 1252` at the beginning of the .bat file. So I tried doing the same thing with the .command file on Mac, so that this became my .command file:

```
chcp 1252
hdiutil convert -format UDZO -o ~/OneDrive/Documents/MittBästaProgram/install-mac-readonly.dmg ~/OneDrive/Documents/Mitt/BästaProgram/install-mac-readandwrite.dmg
```

This didn't either work, it gave me an error saying `chcp: command not found`.

I also tried using `cd` and relative paths like this:

```
cd ~/OneDrive/Documents/MittBästaProgram
hdiutil convert -format UDZO -o install-mac-readonly.dmg install-mac-readandwrite.dmg
```

That gave me the same problem as before, which is that it couldn't find a path containing `ä`. This is the output I got:

```
line 1: cd: /Users/donaldduck/OneDrive/Documents/MittB?staProgram: No such file or directory
```

So my question is how can I use file paths with accented characters such as `ä` in a .command file on Mac?

Comment: You probably need to convert the file to NFD to match the filesystem.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How do I do that?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem.I have a couple of suggestions, though: try viewing the exact encoding of the filename with `cd ~/OneDrive/Documents; echo Mitt* | xxd` -- it *should* be encoded in UTF-8 as "4d69 7474 42**61 cc88** 7374 6150 726f 6772 616d" (with "0a" at the end 'cause `echo` adds that). The "61 cc88" (bolded above) is the important part: 66 is "a", and cc88 is a combining umlaut. Second, try it with a plain-ASCII folder name in your OneDrive folder, and again with an accented-character folder in your Desktop.

Comment: BTW, the `chcp` command ("change code page") and the "code page 1252" character set are both Windows things -- don't try to use them on a Mac. Mac uses Unicode characters (mostly in UTF-8 encoding), and if you need to control what character set it uses at the command line, you need to use the various locale environment variables (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do), for example). But you shouldn't need to mess with that.